# Disable hyperlink on master page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm currently trying to disable a hyperlink on my Master page but it appears it's just not doing it. Everything appears fine and I've been researching for hours with no luck.

Any help would be great.

Code behind

```
(Page.Master.Findcontrol("hlIndex") as Hyperlink).Enabled = false
```

Code on Master page

```
<li><asp:HyperLink ID="hlIndex" href="RGA_index.aspx"  runat="server"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>&nbsp; RGA Index</asp:HyperLink></li>
```

Below is what corrected it and is being used. Thank you for the help!!!

```
<li><asp:HyperLink ID="hlIndex" NavigateUrl="RGA_index.aspx"  runat="server"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>&nbsp; RGA Index</asp:HyperLink></li>
```

Comment: what error does your code throw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are using the HyperLink Control wrong. You need to use the `NavigateUrl` property, not `href`.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlIndex" NavigateUrl="RGA_index.aspx" runat="server">
```

Comment: This removes my Icon and CSS.

Comment: Href its incorrect but I don't think its the cause of the problem. You can even do <a ID="hlIndex" runat= "true"> </a>